# Using slideUp() and slideDown() in condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class='head'>
      <img class='img_plus'> <img class='img_minus'>
</div>
<div> div next head</div>
```

In an accordion, I'd like to check if the div next the head is slide up, it shows .img_plus (+) to head, else if div next head is slide down, it hide (+) and shows .img_minus (-)

Comment: Please add the relevant JS / jQuery you currently have

Comment: Ok, sorry, it's the first time I use the website, I just signed up a few minutes ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".head").each(function(){                 // For each .head element

   $(this).find("img").hide();              // Hide all icons first
   var $nextDiv = $(this).next("div");      // Get the next DIV element

   if( $nextDiv.is(":visible") ) {          // If next DIV is visible
      $(this).find(".img_minus").show();    // Show the - icon
   }else{                                   // Else
      $(this).find(".img_plus").show();     // Show the + icon
   }

});
```